# Integrate facebook details into external site

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to add a feature on my site where when my user signs up, they can login with facebook and the relevant details such as profile pic, status updates etc are shared back and forth.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where to start, google searching has not helped.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this documentation, it will get you started!

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Answer (score 0):

Is it a custom coded site you have made or is it a cms ?, if it is a cms such as Joomla etc, there are lots of Facebook plugins available that can do this sort of thing, this is for Joomla, but there are plenty for everything else too.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/facebook-integration